Error while call_function aten.gather.default Expected dtype int64 for index but got torch.float32 while exporting quantized graph to ExportedProgram
I'm new to Executorch and was trying to convert mDeBERTA model to run on Edge devices. While I was able to at first export the model but post quantization using XNNPACKQuantizer the contized graph is failing to export with the following error
torch._dynamo.exc.TorchRuntimeError: Failed running call_function aten.gather.default(*(FakeTensor(..., size=(12, 28, 512)), -1, FakeTensor(..., size=(12, 28, 28))), **{}): gather(): Expected dtype int64 for index, but got torch.float32
Please find the code snipped below:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch

#from torch.export import export_for_training
#from torch._export import exported_for_training
from torch._export import capture_pre_autograd_graph
from torch.ao.quantization.quantize_pt2e import convert_pt2e, prepare_pt2e
from torch.ao.quantization.quantizer.xnnpack_quantizer import (
    get_symmetric_quantization_config,
    XNNPACKQuantizer,
)

# For Executorch 
from torch.export import export, ExportedProgram
from executorch.exir import to_edge

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
premise = "Angela Merkel ist eine Politikerin in Deutschland und Vorsitzende der CDU"
hypothesis = "Emmanuel Macron is the President of France"
model_name = "MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-mnli-xnli"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, _fast_init=False, torchscript=True)
input = tokenizer(premise, hypothesis, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

input_shape = [251000,768]
input_data = input["input_ids"].to(dtype=torch.int64)
input_data = input_data.type(torch.int64)
print("Input Data: ", input_data, " Datatype: ", type(input_data))
aten_dialect: ExportedProgram = export(model, (input_data,))

print("Got Aten operation")

quantizer = XNNPACKQuantizer().set_global(get_symmetric_quantization_config())
#prepared_graph = prepare_pt2e(aten_dialect, quantizer)
exported_model = capture_pre_autograd_graph(model, (input_data,))
prepared_graph = prepare_pt2e(exported_model, quantizer)
converted_graph = convert_pt2e(prepared_graph)
print("Quantized Graph")


print("Input Data: ", input_data, " Datatype: ", input_data.type())
inpdatai64 = torch.tensor(input_data.tolist(), dtype=torch.int64)
print("Input Data Datatype: ", inpdatai64.type())

# ERROR: The following line results in error with the gather operation 
aten_dialect1: ExportedProgram = export(converted_graph, (inpdatai64,))
print("ATen Dialect Graph")

Note that I have tried with passing dynamic input to export as well but it too ended up in the same error.
What I observe is that it is creating a FakeTensor while tracing the model as part of export. Even if we have passed an input tuple why does it create a FakeTensor? Is there any known issue with FakeTensor or am I missing something while passing the inputs to export.
